# maven javadoc shows annotation twice

Tags: java, java-11, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am trying to add [JetBrains Annotations library](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations) to my code.

Now I come across, that if I generate JavaDoc of my code the appearance of them is duplicated. Once is without qualifier (the annotations are imported, so no one is needed) and the second one (sometimes) with qualifier.
There are also cases where the annotation is only once there but on two parameters one is without qualifier and the other with one.

A code snippet:

```
public Subnet​(@NotNull String[] ip){/*...*/}
/*...*/
public Subnet​(@NotNull int[] ip) {/*...*/}
```

Generated JavaDoc:

```
public Subnet​(@NotNull @NotNull String[] ip){/*...*/}
/*...*/
public Subnet​(@NotNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull int[] ip) {/*...*/}
```

I tried the `-noqualifier` option but it did not help.
I am using the JavaDoc plugin version `3.1.1` and Doclet version `11.0.7`.
Is there a way to get rid of the duplicated annotations?

Comment: found a bug report: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175533

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I seem to have the same problem at the moment which isn't fun...

Comment: unfortunately not